# Sequelize does not join relations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs

I make my own kind of shop. In the user's table, you need to make the fields orders, my products and products that the user bought. You need to join 3 tables together (USERS, ORDERS, GOODS).
I was good at linking only "my products" to the GOODS table. Namely, when a product is created (added), it is automatically created in the GOODS table and immediately attached to the "my goods" field in the USER table. Now I need to connect 2 fields from the USER table with other 2 fields in the ORDERS table, but either it gives me an error, or the order is created only in the ORDERS table without attaching to the fields in the USERS table. Help me.
USERS table:

```
@Table({tableName:'users'})export class User extends Model<User>{

@PrimaryKey
@Column
id: string;

@Column
username: string;

@Column
email: string;

@Column(DataType.STRING(255))
password: string;

@Column
role: string;

@Column
balance: number;

@HasMany(() => Goods)
myGoods: Goods[]


@HasMany(() => Orders, 'SellerOrders')
orders: Orders[]

@HasMany(()=> Orders, 'BuyerPurchasedGoods')
purchasedGoods: Orders[]



@CreatedAt
@Column
createdAt: Date;

@UpdatedAt
@Column
updatedAt: Date;}
```

ORDERS table:

```
@Table({tableName:'orders'}) export class Orders extends Model<Orders>{

@PrimaryKey
@Column
id: string;

@AllowNull(false)
@Column(DataType.JSON)
info: any;

@AllowNull(false)
@Column(DataType.STRING)
state: string;

//USER
@ForeignKey(() => User)
@Column({
  type: DataType.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
})
ownerId: any;

@BelongsTo(() => User, 'SellerOrders')
owner: User;

@ForeignKey(() => User)
@Column({
  type: DataType.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
})
buyerId: any;

@BelongsTo(() => User, "BuyerPurchasedGoods")
buyer: User;

//DATE
@CreatedAt
@Column
createdAt: Date;

@UpdatedAt
@Column
updatedAt: Date;}
```

GOODS table:

```
@Table({tableName:'goods'}) export class Goods extends Model<Goods>{


@PrimaryKey
@Column
id: string;

@AllowNull(false)
@Column
title: string;

@AllowNull(false)
@Column
category: string;

@AllowNull(false)
@Column(DataType.JSON)
info: any

@AllowNull(false)
@Column
price: number;

@AllowNull(false)
@Column
amount: number;

@BelongsTo(() => User)
user: User;

@ForeignKey(() => User)
@Column({
  type: DataType.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
})
userId: string;

@CreatedAt
@Column
createdAt: Date;

@UpdatedAt
@Column
updatedAt: Date;}
```

This is how I create a new product:

```
 try {
        const id = shortid.generate()
        await this.goodsModel.create({ ...createItemDto, id, userId: user.id})
        return 'OK'
    } catch (error) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException('Failure to create new item')
    }
```

And here's the order:

```
 //generate order
    try {
        const id = shortid.generate();
        await this.ordersModel.create({
           id, 
           ownerId: item.userId, 
           buyerId: userObj.id,
           info:{ ...generateOrderDto },
           state:'processing'
        },
        {include:[{all:true}]}
        )
        return 'OK'
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        throw new InternalServerErrorException('Cannot generate order')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. Suddenly it helps someone:
I have incorrectly specified associations in tables. You need to specify the names of the variables.
In ORDERS:

```
@ForeignKey(() => User)
@Column({
  type: DataType.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
})
ownerId: any;

@BelongsTo(() => User, 'ownerId')
owner: User;

@ForeignKey(() => User)
@Column({
  type: DataType.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
})
buyerId: any;

@BelongsTo(() => User, 'buyerId')
buyer: User;
```

And in USERS:

```
    @HasMany(() => Goods)
myGoods: Goods[]


@HasMany(() => Orders, 'ownerId')
orders: Orders[]

@HasMany(()=> Orders, 'buyerId')
purchasedGoods: Orders[]
```

Good luck!